# Yii2 : Switching between production and develop version script in appasset

Tags: yii2

I'm using the appasset file to add my own custom scripts and styles, but I need to debug on the DEV environment, as here I dont want to use the .min files.

I have tried the example below but thats not going to work, is there a way to switch between files here?

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        // this is not going to work
        YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/site.min.js' : 'js/site.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets

Comment: why do you think it wont work the way you tried

Comment: well because it will output an error

Comment: no it wont if you wrap it in parenthesis`()` it works for me correctly `(YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/site.min.js' : 'js/site.js'),` apart  from that you need to swap the conditions

Comment: You can use expressions as default values of properties since PHP 5.6 (EOLed a month ago) - it is time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];

 public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->js[] = YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/site.min.js' : 'js/site.js';
    }
}
```